# Does AB = 0 mean that BZA = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

Simple linear algebra question, but I can't offer a rigorous proof. Given $A$ and $B$ non-square matrices and knowing

$ AB = 0$

does this imply that

$BZA = 0$,

where $Z$ is an arbitrary matrix with dimensions such that $BZA$ is conformable for multiplication?

I think it does because each row nonzero row in A must be multiplied by a column of zeros in B, so the product will vanish regardless of the $Z$. But I'm having trouble being more rigorous or finding a property that proves this explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...each row nonzero row in A must be multiplied by a column of zeros in B": Not so. E.g. $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$.

Comment: Try $A=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 2  \\
   1 & 2  \\
   1 & 2  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$, $B=\left( \begin{matrix}
   -2  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$,  $Z=\left( \begin{matrix}
   1 & 1 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,
$Z=I$.

Comment: Perfect. Not thinking clearly today, apparently. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. Consider $A = [1, 0]$ and $B = [0,1]^t$. Then clearly $BA = 0$. However, if you compute $AB$ you get 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Best answer for doing it with non-square matrices, just like OP ordered:P

Comment: "The OP ordered"? Well, now that's new...and some obey?

Answer (score 0):

$AB=0$ does not even imply that $BA=0$. Take $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)$ and $B= \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right)$.